# How to make ajax return markup instead of raw text

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want my ajax to return markup instead of raw text. Of course php can echo out labels or paragraphs etc. I have 2 functions:

file1:

```
function updateHtmlContent() {
    var htmlContent = $('#new-users').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "object",
        url: "newusers.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (htmlContent != data) {
                $('#new-users').text(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

#new-users is just an empty div

File 2 :

```
session_start();
include("../class/Database.php");
$roomData = Database::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE roomId = '".$_SESSION['roomcode']."'");
$roomData2 = Database::query("SELECT * FROM room WHERE code = '".$_SESSION['roomcode']."'");
foreach ($roomData as $name){
    if ($name['username'] == $roomData2[0]['hostname']){
    } else {
        echo "<a href='#'>".$name['username']."</a>";
        echo "<label>€".$name['money']."</label>";
    }
}
```

But this just literally returns: `<a href='#'>` instead of just the markup with the content in it. I dont want the `<a href='#'>` to be visible just the text inside it

Comment: Empty IF's are very Odd and unprofessional. You could use `if ($name['username'] !== $roomData2[0]['hostname']){`

Comment: `dataType` should be `html` also `$('#new-users').text(data);`  should be  `$('#new-users').html(data);`

Comment: your database queries are open to sql injection (you should use prepared queries instead), but as to your question; I'm not sure i fully understand you correctly but it sounds like you just want `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: `$('#new-users').text(data);` --> `$('#new-users').html(data);`